# Are the changed variables of a class reset when test function is finished?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

My question is, If we have 2 different Test functions, and we change a class variable `a.something` in first Test function and use this variable in Assert statement.
Then we continue with other Test function. It also changes `a.something` and uses it in Assert statement.
Will `a.something` reset when we start executing second Test function?
If yes, is there a way to remove it from memory to not effect second test result?

Comment: It'd be useful to see some example code for this. The smallest way you can represent the question

Comment: If you reuse the same instance in multiple tests then no, the values are not reset. That's why there are certain mechanics used in various test frameworks (for example `@Before` in JUnit) where you setup a fresh test scaffold every time before an actual test is run. Remember, tests need to be repeatable and deterministic and should not depend on each other. So it's best to make sure you always have "fresh" data.

Comment: @QBrute I got it. I should use different variables or get help with frameworks. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are. The following tests will always pass.

```
public class MyTestClass {

    String myString;

    @Test
    void Test1() {
        myString = "Hello World";
        assertNotNull(this.myString);
    }

    @Test
    void Test2() {
        assertNull(this.myString);
    }
}
```